# How can hourly ERA5 data be converted to daily data?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm going to convert the hourly data into average, maximum, and minimum data and then calculate the reference evaporation and transpiration based on that, but finally I get an error. How can I correct my code.

```
var table = ee.Geometry.Point(38.42, 37.42);
 Map.centerObject(table)

// PENMANMONTEITH computes potential evapotranspiration Era5_land

 //Start and End date for 8 day period
var startDate = ('2010-05-01')
var endDate   =  ('2010-05-10')


//  constants
                            //<<<<<< Define constants.>>>>>>>
var G = 0;

// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Tmean
var temporalCollection = function(collection, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units);
    
    return collection
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean().clip(table)
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis())
  }));
};


var Tmean = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('temperature_2m').clip(table).rename('mean_2m_air_temperature');
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames());
};


var eraland5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
// .filterDate('2010-05-01','2010-06-02')
.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(Tmean)

var eradaily_Tmean = temporalCollection(eraland5, startDate, 30, 1, 'day');
eradaily_Tmean = eradaily_Tmean.map(function(img1) {
  var vci = img1.rename('mean_2m_air_temperature')

  return img1.addBands([vci]);
  
});

var temporalCollection_max = function(collection1, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units);
    
    return collection1
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate).max().clip(table)
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis())
  }));
};

var Tmax = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('temperature_2m').clip(table).rename('maximum_2m_air_temperature');
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames());
};

var eraland5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
// .filterDate('2010-05-01','2010-06-02')
.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(Tmax)

var eradaily_Tmax = temporalCollection_max(eraland5, startDate, 30, 1, 'day');
eradaily_Tmax = eradaily_Tmax.map(function(img1) {
  var vci = img1.rename('maximum_2m_air_temperature')

  return img1.addBands([vci]);
  
});

var temporalCollection_min = function(collection2, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units);
    
    return collection2
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate).min().clip(table)
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis())
  }));
};


var Tmin = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('temperature_2m').clip(table).rename('minimum_2m_air_temperature');
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames());
};


var eraland5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
// .filterDate('2010-05-01','2010-06-02')
.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(Tmin)

var eradaily_Tmin = temporalCollection_min(eraland5, startDate, 30, 1, 'day');
eradaily_Tmin = eradaily_Tmin.map(function(img1) {
  var vci = img1.rename('minimum_2m_air_temperature')

  return img1.addBands([vci]);
  
});

var temporalCollection_uwind = function(collection3, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units);
    
    return collection3
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean().clip(table)
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis())
  }));
};


var uwind = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('u_component_of_wind_10m').clip(table).rename('u_component_of_wind_10m');
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames());
};


var eraland5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
// .filterDate('2010-05-01','2010-06-02')
.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(uwind)

var eradaily_uwind = temporalCollection_uwind(eraland5, startDate, 30, 1, 'day');
eradaily_uwind = eradaily_uwind.map(function(img1) {
  var vci = img1.rename('u_component_of_wind_10m')

  return img1.addBands([vci]);
  
});

var temporalCollection_vwind = function(collection4, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units);
    
    return collection4
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean().clip(table)
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis())
  }));
};


var vwind = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('v_component_of_wind_10m').clip(table).rename('v_component_of_wind_10m');
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames());
};

var eraland5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
// .filterDate('2010-05-01','2010-06-02')
.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(vwind)

var eradaily_vwind = temporalCollection_uwind(eraland5, startDate, 30, 1, 'day');
eradaily_vwind = eradaily_vwind.map(function(img1) {
  var vci = img1.rename('v_component_of_wind_10m')

  return img1.addBands([vci]);
  
});
print(eradaily_vwind)

//Ancillary data for dT calculation
var pi1 = Math.PI;
var Elev1 = ee.Image("USGS/GTOPO30").select([0], ['elev']);
var Lat1 = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(['latitude']).multiply(pi1/180);


//PENMANMONTEITH
function et0_func(temperature_image) {
  var image_date = ee.Algorithms.Date(temperature_image.get("system:time_start"));
  var doy1 = ee.Number(image_date.getRelative('day', 'year')).add(1).double();

  // Extract min and max temperaute images 
  var Wind_U_date = temperature_image.select("u_component_of_wind_10m");
  var Wind_V_date = temperature_image.select("v_component_of_wind_10m");
  var u2 = temperature_image.expression('sqrt(u**2 + v**2)',{'u':Wind_U_date,'v':Wind_V_date});
  // var SWdown_daily_mean = temperature_image.select("Downward_Short-Wave_Radiation_Flux_surface_6_Hour_Average");
  // var Qair_daily_mean = temperature_image.select("Specific_humidity_height_above_ground");
  
  var minimum_2m_air_temperature = temperature_image.select("minimum_2m_air_temperature");
 
  var mean_2m_air_temperature = temperature_image.select("mean_2m_air_temperature");
// print(mean_2m_air_temperature)
   
  var maximum_2m_air_temperature = temperature_image.select("maximum_2m_air_temperature");

  // Make a DOY image from the DOY number
  doy1 = Wind_V_date.multiply(0).add(doy1);

  //Clear Sky Solar Radiation (Rso) from FAO 56
  // Extraterrestrial radiation (Eqn 24, 25, 23, 21)
  var D11 = doy1.multiply(2 * pi1 / 365).subtract(1.39435).sin().multiply(0.40928);
  //var D1 = ee.Image.constant(doy.multiply(2 * pi / 365).subtract(1.39435).sin().multiply(0.40928));
  //Map.addLayer(D1);
  var Ws1 = Lat1.expression('acos(-tan(Lat) * tan(D1))', {'Lat':Lat1, 'D1':D11});
  //Map.addLayer(Ws);
  var Raa1 = Ws1.expression(
    'Ws * sin(Lat) * sin(D1) + cos(Lat) * cos(D1) * sin(Ws)',
    {'Ws':Ws1, 'Lat':Lat1, 'D1':D11});
  //Map.addLayer(Raa);
  var Dr1 = doy1.multiply(2 * pi1 / 365).cos().multiply(0.033).add(1);
  //var Dr = ee.Image.constant(doy.multiply(2 * pi / 365).cos().multiply(0.033).add(1));
  //Map.addLayer(Dr);
  var Ra1 = Raa1.expression('(1367.0 / pi) * 0.0820 * Dr * Raa', {'pi':pi1, 'Dr':Dr1, 'Raa':Raa1});
  //var Ra = Raa.expression('(1367.0 / pi) * Dr * Raa', {'pi':pi, 'Dr':Dr, 'Raa':Raa});
  //Map.addLayer(Ra);
  
  
  // Simplified clear sky solar formulation (Eqn 37)
  var Rso1 = Ra1.expression('(0.75 + 2E-5 * Elev) * Ra', {'Elev':Elev1, 'Ra':Ra1}); //}
  //Map.addLayer(Rso);

  // Net shortwave radiation (Eqn 38) use albedo = 0.23
  var Rns1 = Rso1.multiply(1-0.23);
  
    var ea1 = Rns1.expression(
    '0.6108 * exp((17.27 * (minimum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16)) / ((minimum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16) + 237.3))', 
    {'minimum_2m_air_temperature':minimum_2m_air_temperature});

  var Rnl1 = ea1.expression(
    '4.901E-9 * 0.5 * ((maximum_2m_air_temperature -273.16) ** 4 + (minimum_2m_air_temperature -273.16) ** 4) * (0.34 - 0.14 * sqrt(Ea))',
    {'maximum_2m_air_temperature':maximum_2m_air_temperature, 'minimum_2m_air_temperature':minimum_2m_air_temperature, 'Ea':ea1});

  var Rn = Rns1.subtract(Rnl1);
  var Pair1 = Elev1.expression(
    '101.3 * pow((293.0 - 0.0065 * Elev) / 293.0, 5.26)', 
    {'Elev':Elev1});

  var sa1 = Pair1.expression('0.665 * (10**-3) * P',{'P':Pair1});
  // var sa = Pair.expression('0.000665 * P',{'P':Pair});

  var e0Tmax  = sa1.expression(
    '0.6108 *( exp((17.27 * (maximum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16)) / ((maximum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16) + 237.3)))', 
    {'maximum_2m_air_temperature':maximum_2m_air_temperature});

var e0Tmin  = e0Tmax.expression(
    '0.6108 * exp((17.27 * (minimum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16)) / ((minimum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16) + 237.3))', 
    {'minimum_2m_air_temperature':minimum_2m_air_temperature});

    var e0Tmean = e0Tmin.expression(
    '0.6108 * exp((17.27 * (minimum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16)) / ((minimum_2m_air_temperature - 273.16) + 237.3))', 
    {'minimum_2m_air_temperature':minimum_2m_air_temperature});
    
    
  var es =  e0Tmin.expression(
    ' (e0Tmax + e0Tmin) /2', 
    {'e0Tmax':e0Tmax,
    'e0Tmin':e0Tmin});

var  delta1  = es.expression('4098 * (0.6108 *(exp((17.27 * ((Tmean - 273.16 )- 273.16))/((Tmean- 273.16)+237.3))))',
{'Tmean'
:mean_2m_air_temperature});

var  delta2 = delta1.expression('(Tmean -273.16 ) + (56311.29)',
{'Tmean'
:mean_2m_air_temperature});

var  delta = delta1 .divide(delta2) ;

var ET01  =  delta2.expression(
    '  ((( 0.408 * delta) *( Rn-G ))+( sa * (900 /(( (Tmean -273.15) +273 )))) * (u2 *( es-ea ) ))/( delta +( sa * ( 1 + 0.34 * u2 )) )',
    {'Rn':Rn, 'G':G, 'delta':delta, 'sa':sa1, 'u2':u2, 'Tmean':mean_2m_air_temperature, 'es':es, 'ea':ea1  });

   
var ET0 = ET01.where(ET01.lte(0),0.01)
  .resample('bilinear').clip(table);
 
  return ET0.select([0], ['eto'])
    .copyProperties(temperature_image, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']); 
}
var pet_coll = ee.ImageCollection(stacked_composite)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(et0_func);

print(pet_coll)

// var ET01 = pet_coll.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).clip(table);
  
var collection = pet_coll.select('eto');
var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
var filtered = filtered.map(function(image) {
  return image.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/132c4aec6030c83f17e9d88035d02293?noload=true

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions here should include the relevant code *in the body of the Question* along with the exact error message (as text). Please [Edit] your Question.

Comment: Error is produced because **stacked_composite** is not defined.